# Sorting Column by clicking column header in php web page

Tags: php, jquery, sorting, html-table, multiple-columns

I have one page which has a button that clicks and displays all the data from the database in the table with jquery. I need to sort the table by clicking the column head. problem is that i have is, the way the table is populated.  see the code. I have php code which populates it. The columns are ID, Licence etc. So I need to sort it on based of column.

```
<?php

    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $query = "
        my query from database to display all the values
                                ";
                        $result= $dbh->prepare($query,array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
                        $result->execute();

                        echo "<table id='abc' class='abcd' width='100%'><tr>"
                            . "<th id='mydata' class='myd' onclick='loadOrderedData(myd)'>ABC</th>"
                            . "<th>DEF</th>"
                            .......
                            . "</tr>";

                        while($data=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT))
                        {
                            echo "<tr>"
                                . "<td>" . $data['ABC'] . "</td>"
                                . "<td>" . $data['DEF'] . "</td>"
                                .......
                                . "</tr>";

                        }

                        echo "</table>";
                    ?>
```

it is displayed in a div which is hidden at first and then using jquery it is made un-hidden on the button click which fetches the data. Please help me with the viable solution.

I tried making `<a href="#" >` and making use of onclick method. It doesn't work, may be due to how it populates the data.

Comment: You can do it a few ways, either post to the page with the column clicked and use an ORDER BY clause in your query, use an ajax call to reload the data and send the column clicked as a parameter and again use ORDER BY, or you can store the data in a javascript array instead of a php array and resort it based on which column the user clicks. I prefer either of the two former to the latter

Comment: Can you provide me some links pertaining to this behaviour? thanks for the help !!

Comment: Since you are already using jquery maybe [datatables](https://datatables.net/) would be an option.

Comment: I'll post some info in the form of an answer to give some examples.

Comment: Thanks bryan !! i have posted the code snippet of my implementation. Can you let me know according to that. thanks Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Pertaining to the ops question in comments...
an example query using order by...

```
 SELECT * FROM `my_table` ORDER BY `price` ASC
```

.... this returns the results ordered by the values in the price column. using ajax you can use jQuerys .load function. and pass the url with a get variable for which column to sort by,
You'll need to give your < tr > an id, ill call the id 'data' and the columns you'll click would have an onclick="loadOrderedData(columnName)" attribute call load function like...

```
function loadOrderedData(orderBy){
 $('#data').load('aPhpPageThatReturnsData.php?orderBy='+orderBy);
}
```

so in the file being called the query might look like

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` ORDER BY `$_GET['orderBy']` ASC 
//code to create new html for your data <tr> using sorted data
```

Hopefully that helps.
update ....

```
$result->execute();
?>
<table id='abc' class='abcd' width='100%'>
    <tr>
        <th class='myd' onclick='loadOrderedData("myd")'>ABC</th>
        <th>DEF</th>
     </tr>
      <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
             <table id="myData">
    <?php
while($data=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT))
{ ?>
                <tr>
                   <td><?=$data['ABC']?></td>
                   <td><?=$data['DEF']?></td>
                </tr>
<?php
} ?>
         </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: I have the query already sorted with order by command. my php loading of table has each row and column to which i assign the id and class. Now when i am trying to click on the column using onclick as suggest by you, it is not working. I need to stay on same page, and just want only the contents of table changes. not the whole page refreshes.

Comment: yeah you have to use ajax to make that happen, if onclick isn't working, you're doing something wrong. first check your web developers error console to see if you have a javascript error, what browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Chrome. I am new to this and i am confused as in how to make a ajax call to update the table whenever i click on it, either it refreshes page to its initial state or goes unaffected. like in example above, ABC is one column. now i make id and class of it, call it with onclick. but i have my query already runningabove after connecting to db, how do i override that one

Comment: Update your question code including the html elemts with the onclick attribute and the jquery and it'll be a lot easier to troubleshoot. the .load jquery function does all the work for you as far as ajax is concerned. sounds to me like you're using a form element as your 'button' to resort the table, this will cause a page refresh

Comment: also just a tip for debugging with javascript, I like to use an alert to make sure the javascript im expecting to be triggered is triggered. ie, in my loadOrderedData function i would add an alert('in function') so i know if it's being triggered or not.

Comment: updated the code with column onclick method, and then i am using this in script..      function loadOrderedData(orderBy){
     $('#mydata').load('adddata.php?orderBy='+orderBy);
   }

Comment: myd is nothing. if it's a column in your database it needs to be "myd" with quotes, javascript is expecting a variable otherwise.

Comment: in chrome click the three lines icon on the top right->tools->developer tools it would have told you where the javascript error was.

Comment: It is in the quotes only, single quotes due to php code embedded with html. With double quotes it throws error

Comment: inside function its in quotes, my typo error in the snippet. Do we need to give ahref to the column.?

Comment: change this line..  "<th id='mydata' class='myd' onclick='loadOrderedData(\"myd\")'>ABC</th>" the function argument needs to be in quotes.

Comment: Okay. javascript is being called. Now , it is my same page where table is displayed. when i am calling javascript on click, it places page contents in that header. any points on that. how to sort it

Comment: the .load event loads the content into whatever you tell it to, remove id="myData" from the table header and add id="myData" to the row you want the data placed in. im going to update my answer so you can just use that code.

Comment: try that, also i hate tables, hopefully that works for you though. haha.

Comment: Yes i understand what you update the code. but content of load is the issue. giving it the .php file  uploads whole page with all buttons , but no data inside that row. i have done exactly the same as you have done

Comment: post the contents of adddata.php

Comment: it is a huge file. containing the whole page. having buttons and each buttons signifying some ajax request and some forms to be filled

Comment: that's wrong. it only needs to contain the code generated in the while loop. what the jquery load() function does is loads whatever is in the file you are calling to the place you told it to, in the case of my code, it loads whatever content is in adddata.php to the table with id "myData" if you have the whole page in adddata.php it's expected the whole page will load in the table where id ="myData"

Comment: yes. So shall i make another file calling the same piece of code , that is the query. Idont think so it is optimal. thats why i am facing issues, as populating the table is being done on the same file. thats a big thing

Comment: no, just change adddata.php to only be the while loop. unless you're using that file for something else in which case, yes create a new file that only outputs table rows ordered by the get parameter. and also change the jquery function to call that page.

Comment: hmm okay.. thanks a lot. now i get it. i will try it again with the new page and will post the result.

Comment: Thanks you buddy !! it was of great help.Many things got cleared. Thanks again.. will get back

Comment: Not yet though .If i make another page, then i have to include it in previous page as include('newfile.php');. then it displays the contents on load .. how to include it?

Comment: do not include it. the contents will be put in the table when the .load function is called.(when you click a sort table heading)

Comment: Nope, it doesnt do that. Nothing is happening on clicking the column. id is  defined in other file and it is being used by load in some other file. will that work

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. It does do that. jQuery just works. And that is how it works, i don't think you're understanding what should happen when the onclick event is triggered.

Comment: lets take this to a private conversation.

Comment: ah you can't chat yet.

Comment: is this a live project or local, if it's live give me a link so i can see what is happening.

Comment: yes its a live project, but its a backend of project and i am not allowed to provide further information..  You can see it like, we log in into management sysytem, which has a side navigation of the full website, on clicking one of the links, we get a page named abc.php , there side navigation still remains. also has 4 buttons on the top. one is to view all the things in form of table. now i need to sort that table columns. and that table only needs to be refreshed once i click on the header not whole page.. i hope it clears

Comment: I understand what you're trying to accomplish. There is plenty of information here for you to get it done. If you need more help provide me with javascript errors you're getting or something constructive. Repeating what you need done isn't helping me understand where it's broken. Best of luck otherwise.

Comment: I made it working by making different queries for each row. but the new issue i am facing is. when i click on column header, it sorts, but my table disaapears. Now i have to click on button again to bring the sorted table back. i know its stupid, but the thing my button is doing that is making the div unhidden can be aaplied on ahref also.. but oit is not working? any points on that

Comment: is the table just hidden or is the html for it gone?

Comment: there is one div which displays all the data of the table on clicking of the button. onclick of button it is unhide("div name"); and that div class is hidden..

Comment: <th><a href='?sort=Licence'>License</a></th>" .. how can i add unhide the table dding to this hyperlink.. i did <th><a href='?sort=ID' onclick=\"unhide('div id');\">ID</a></th>".. but it doesnt work

Comment: Cann i change the div class name on click of that href. As the div has a class hidden. so i understood, it will be hidden once i click the link.

Comment: Issue Resolved.. Thanks mate for all your comments. I did it by changing the query, then hidding and making the elements visible on other button clicks. Trivial but hell lot of understanding with concepts. thanks again. Cheers